# Finding Files Relative my Codes File Path - Python/Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, filepath

So I have been looking a bit online and can't what i'm looking for.

Pretty much I want a way to have my code in one folder, and then my pictures in another subfolder.

**Code's file path example**: Downloads\my-game\my-code

**Images' file path example**: Downloads\my-game\pictures\my-picture

Is there a way I can do something like

```
    pygame.image.load(...\pictures\my-picture)
```

or would I have to use a full file path?
The reason I don't want to use a full file path is so that I can move the entire folder around without needing to remake all of the file paths.

Comment: Use the predefined `__file__` attribute to get the path to the script file and then use `os.path.dirname()` to get the name of the directory it's in from that and then join it with the name of subdirectory contain the image files.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `pygame.image.load('./pictures/my-picture')`